# How let IIS connect to wan-computers by the ip4 address

Tags: iis

I have two ip-addresses. One is ip4. When I visit a site that shows the ip it is not shown but another address.

I must fill in the ip4 address in IIS to make the site work. If external computers want to visit it, I must use the other address, give that out.

How can I make my IIS website available trough the ip4 address? My OS is Windows 7 sp1.

Comment: You need to give more detail here. Where are you getting these IPs from? Does either of them start with 192. or 10.? Is this on your home network? Please edit your question and add extra detail.

Comment: What I'm really looking for is: how can I run a site in IIS that only uses one ip-address. 


By ip4 I meant an address that starts with 192. That is the one I have to fill in in "bindings". Any other will not work in whatever way. If I check what my ip is on a site for it I get to see a different number. It starts with 182.

On my pc I can view my IIS site using that 192 : portnumber , but if an external pc wants to do that or me behind a proxy it has to use that 182 address.

Comment: This is possible but if you're doing this from your home network it's a bad idea because your external IP address (the 182 one) will change regularly unless you've specifically bought a fixed IP from your ISP. You can use a dynamic dns service to get around that problem.

Comment: your external IP address (the 182 one) will change regularly: That is not a problem. Which settings do I have to apply to get an one ip?

Comment: The handiest way I can think to do it is to edit the hosts file on your computer so that when it looks for the 192 address it resolves to the 182 address. But as I say every time the IP changes you'll have to edit it again, and your binding if you're binding to the external address. Why do you need them to be exactly the same though? If it's working fine using the local IP in bindings and the external one for access, what's the problem?